# What does どういった mean in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

> その場面というのは**どういった**場面かというと、ナチスの兵士がですね、ユダヤ人を職業別で分けていきます。

Source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3xs-XWk_oQA 0:55

Translation from subtitles: There’s a scene where the Nazi’s are separating the Jewish by their occupation.

Is どう in this case the "how" adverb? Is いった an inflection of いる, to exist?

Comment: This is the third time you asked about this sentence (after [this](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/31022/5010) and [this](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/33503/5010)), all regarding "いう" in the first half of the sentence. It's okay, but I'm interested in why. Are you not satisfied with the existing answers?

Comment: I think everyone has done a good job answering my question regarding this sentence, but I wasn't completely comfortable moving on before making a distinction between は and というのは. It's hard to tell sometimes whether certain words in Japanese contain certain sounds by coincidence or if they are some kind of compound made up of smaller particles. In this case というのは does seem to have a meaning related to 言う in the sense that it is referring to something that was previously "said" or "talked about". I guess it's a question of morphology, and it's the same thing I'm trying to figure out here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

どういった is a fixed expression which is the same as どのような or どういう, meaning "what kind of". どういった is a bit euphemistic and politer than the others.

> - どういったご用件ですか？ May I ask what this is regarding?
> - ○○はどういった意味ですか？ What does ○○ mean?